# Extract data from 2d array

Tags: swift

I have an array which has 4 rows and 100,000 columns.

I would like to get only first column's 400 rows data points.

I am trying to achieve it as follows but it returns only the first row. I am wondering what I am doing wrong?

```
data[0...400][0]
```

Comment: The suffix `[0]` fetches the first element of _one_ array. That, in your code, is the first row, whether you include 100,000 other rows or 400 other rows.

Comment: @matt, could you please elaborate a little bit in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to say is `data[0..<400].map{$0[0]}`. (Note that I changed your `...` to `..<`, as otherwise you will have the first 401 rows which is not what you said you wanted.)